# Afterpay payment gateway response issue

Tags: php, curl, payment

I am integrating afterpay payment gateway by the help of
https://developers.afterpay.com/afterpay-online/reference#create-checkout-1 this page.
I added all required parms in curl header. but i am getting error in curl response.
I searched alot but didnt got any solution, please suggest any tutorial that works properly or give any solution.
here is my curl code

```
private function requestCurl($data){
    $array = array(
      'amount' => [
          'amount' => number_format((float)$data['amount'], 2, '.', ''),
          'currency' => 'USD'
      ],
      'consumer' => [
          'givenNames' => $data['first_name'],
          'surname' =>  $data['last_name'],
          'email' => $data['email']
      ],
      'billing' => [
          'name' => $data['first_name'] . ' '. $data['last_name'],
          'line1' => $data['address'],
          "area1" => "San Francisco",
          "region"=> "CA",
          "countryCode"=> "US",
          'postcode' => $data['zip_code']
      ],
      'shipping' => [
          'name' => $data['first_name'] . ' '. $data['last_name'],
          'line1' => $data['address'],
          "area1" => "San Francisco",
          "region"=> "CA",
          "countryCode"=> "US",
          'postcode' => $data['zip_code']
      ],
      'merchant' => [
          'redirectConfirmUrl' => 'https://localhost/beauty/public/checkout/success',
          'redirectCancelUrl' => 'https://localhost/beuty/public/cart'
      ],
      'taxAmount' => [
          'amount' => 0.00,
          'currency' => 'USD'
      ],
      'shippingAmount' => [
          'amount' => 5.00,
          'currency' => 'USD'
      ]
    );

  


    $_h = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($_h, [
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.us-sandbox.afterpay.com/v2/checkouts",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($array),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Authorization: Basic MYID",
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "User-Agent: Readme.io API Simulator"
        ],
    ]);



    echo "<pre>", print_r(curl_exec($_h));  
}
```

and i am getting this in response

```
 {
  "errorCode" : "error",
  "errorId" : "f91a4cc29d926c20",
  "message" : "An error occurred processing your request",
  "httpStatusCode" : 500
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If it’s error 500, that means it’s their error. Plus you leaked your client ID (or something like that. Edit question and consider looking for http statuses explanation.

Comment: client ID is the dummy text, not my ID :-)

Answer (score 1):

This resource from Afterpay's public Github repo may be useful:
https://github.com/afterpay/sdk-php#troubleshooting

The first thing to try is – Pass the raw values into the `amount` object. This applies for `amount`, `taxAmount`, and `shippingAmount`
eg)

```
'amount' =>[ number_format((float)$data['amount'], 2, '.', '') , 'USD']
```

I also noticed a misspelling in the `redirectCancelURL`,
I believe the path should be: `https://localhost/beuaty/public/cart'`

Comment: Thanks Dear, I corrected the redirectCancelUrl, and also passed the amout value 100.00
but still got same error :-(

Comment: Tried with  https://github.com/afterpay/sdk-php#troubleshooting this sdk
got the same error in response